# jQuery-UI Slider Background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Is it possible to set background color (via JavaScript) of jQuery-UI Slider widget?

This is normal:

[image: normal behavior]

What I am looking to achieve is following:

[image: with background]

Green range would be calculated based on historical data. I would like to indicate to user what is a "healthy" range.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery UI does not offer such a feature, but it is not difficult to implement it.

```
$.fn.addRange = function (min, max) {
  this.prepend('<div class=range></div>');
  $range = this.find('.range');
  $range.css("left", min * 100 + '%');
  $range.css("right", 100 - (max * 100) + '%');
};

var $slider = $('#slider');
$slider.slider();
$slider.addRange(0.2, 0.4);
```

This adds a `<div class=range></div>` inside the slider and sets its `left` and `right` CSS properties to 20% and 40%.

And the accompanying CSS:

```
#slider {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: none;
}

.range {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

Demo: http://jsbin.com/eheden/1/edit